# PyPDF2 TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, pypdf

Here are my code my objective is I want to crop pdf with the specific margin but it return me error that is

`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader=PdfReader('Flipkart_Test.pdf','r')
writer=PdfWriter()

print("Total PDF Pages",len(reader.pages))
page=reader.pages[4]
# The `print(page)` statement is printing the information about the `page` object.
# print(page)

print(page.mediabox.left)
print(page.mediabox.right)
print(page.mediabox.top)
print(page.mediabox.bottom)
crop_left=(180.0,0)

print(crop_left[0])
for i in range(len(reader.pages)):
       page=reader.pages[i]
       page.cropbox.lower_left(crop_left)
       page.cropbox.upper_right((100,120))
       write.addPage(page)

outstream= open('Flipkart_Crop.pdf','wb')
writer.write(outstream)
outstream.close()
```

How to remove above error?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PyPDF new documentation you should assgin value instead of passing the value

```
for i in range(len(reader.pages)):
       page=reader.pages[i]
       page.cropbox.lower_left=crop_left
       page.cropbox.upper_right=(100,120)
       write.addPage(page)
```